# SQL SELECT using a "join table"

Tags: mysql, sql, join

1. Table **Student** maps **Student.student_name** to **Student.student_id**
2. Table **Course** maps **Course.course_name** to **Course.course_id**
3. Table **Enrollment** maps **Enrollment.student_id** to **Enrollment.course_id** (I've heard this referred to as a *join table*.)

What is the SELECT statement that, given a student name, will return his list of course names?  I think this may be some of it:

```
SELECT c.course_name FROM Course c 
INNER JOIN Enrollment e ON c.course_id = e.course_id 
...
WHERE s.student_name = 'Tom';
```

Beyond that, I'm clueless.

(This isn't homework, it's just a simplification of a work problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.course_name FROM Enrollment e 
INNER JOIN Course c ON c.course_id = e.course_id 
INNER JOIN Student s ON s.student_id = e.student_id 
WHERE s.student_name = 'Tom';
```

also

```
SELECT c.course_name 
FROM Enrollment e, Course c, Student s
WHERE c.course_id = e.course_id 
  AND s.student_id = e.student_id 
  AND s.student_name = 'Tom';
```

Comment: It sure did.  Thanks!  (Edit: I used your first solution, with INNER JOIN -- is there any reason to prefer the second solution?)

Comment: And much easier to understand, too.